# Pass scraped item as json to a PHP script

Tags: php, python, json, scrapy

So I want to pass my scraped items to a php script, I have in my pipeline:

```
class TalkPhpPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        toPHP = json.dumps(dict(item))

        os.system( '/usr/bin/php script.php %s' % toPHP)
        return item
```

and in my script.php

```
<? require_once('wp-config.php');
$string = $argv[1];
echo 'PHP see this ';
var_dump($string);
```

The spider talks to script.php just fine, however my script.php only sees a srting of lenght 7 like this `{title:`, if I instead replace toPHP with `item['title']`, then the php side sees `[usomewhere only we know]`, what I really want to pass to php is a string like:
`{'title': [u'somewhere only we know']}` or just `{'title': ['somewhere only we know']}`, of course with all other fields that my item contains, how do I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is messing with the quotes in the command line. So use a different function (such as [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)) that allows you to specify individual arguments:

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/php', 'script.php', json.dumps(dict(item))])
```

Note that unless the JSON is very short, you may be better off just passing it to PHP in a different way, such as through a pipe, because operating systems have command line length limits.

In Python, you could use the `subprocess.Popen` class to pipe the JSON to the PHP script, which could retrieve the JSON using `fgets(STDIN)`.